# Why am I getting an error when installing the latest version of npm?

Tags: ubuntu, npm, npm-install

my current npm version is 3.5.2. I want to update npm and sudo npm install npm @ latest -g I am typing this command. I tried deleting the package.json but I get this error below.
[image]

Comment: That is really hard to read. Please post actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue today. Nothing worked, and I found lots of bug reports for similar issues. The solution was to [use a version manager like `nvm`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04#option-3-%E2%80%94-installing-node-using-the-node-version-manager).

(Optional) If you are running Ubuntu, you can remove the currently installed system-wide versions of `nodejs` and `npm` like this:

```sh
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
```

Following are the exact commands I typed to install fresh versions in my user directory. All permission issues go away as a result. These commands probably will work for all OSes with only a slight change:

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc  # this line might change
nvm install v15.12.0
npm install -g npm@7.7.5
```

If you have a Mac, `source ~/.bash_profile` instead.
... unless you are running zsh, in which case you need to `source ~/.zshrc`. If all else fails, `source ~/.profile`.

[For more info](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)